# Rem not compatible with media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using **CSS breakpoints** to update the font-size on my site.
Regular text respond as expected, but the text affected by a class using **rem** value doesn't.
Anyone have an idea why?
*(Try the snippet in full page and resize your browser)*

```css
body { font-size: 22px; }
.test { font-size: 2rem; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
 body { font-size: 20px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 body { font-size: 17px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
 body { font-size: 15px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 648px) {
 body { font-size: 18px; }
}
```

```html
Example
<div class="test">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rem` sizes the font based on the 'root element', hence `rem`. The root element is actually the `html` element, not the `body`. So, changing the font size of the `body` element is no longer relevant when you're then defining the font size of a subelement based on its parent.

Replace `body` with `html` in your sample and it'll work fine.

Comment: Man, almost the same response right down to the closing.

Comment: Did beat you to it by 11 seconds though  :P

Answer (score 3):

You're setting the `font-size` on the wrong element.  `rem` is the ***Root*** `em` unit.  The document root isn't `body`, but `html`.

If you change all those `body` references to `html` references, everything will work fine.