# need to make this below range slider Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, frontend

I need to make this Range slider responsive. Text is getting overlapped when i start using in mobile version. Please help me to achieve this.

I have tried to add it in Table responsive and adding some responsive divs but still it didn't workout.

It would be great if someone help me to find out the way to make it responsive. You can see executable code in

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran" rel="stylesheet);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script");

  

.label-container {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.label-slider {
  color: #3949ab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(2) {
  padding-left: 18px;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 34px;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(4) {
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(5) {
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #dde5ff;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

input[type="range"],
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #dde5ff;
  outline: none;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2b8aeb;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1492ea;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
    <p class="title">Range Sliders</p>

    <h4>Range Slider without steps</h4>
    <div class="slider-container">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="4" class="slider">
    </div>

    <div class="label-container">
      <div class="label-slider">None</div>
      <div class="label-slider">1</div>
      <div class="label-slider">2</div>
      <div class="label-slider">3</div>
      <div class="label-slider">4+</div>
    </div>

    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `width: 600px` by `max-width:600px;` in container.

For the font-size, I would recommand you to set font size based in rem. and set breakpoints font-size on your html element to size as you wish. as this subject: [Rem not compatible with media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051179/rem-not-compatible-with-media-queries)

Ad I will also recommand you to remove container padding-left and right when you under a certain width of screen, this way, the scale will stay well align with your input.

### Edit

To fix the the container label, I set them with position absolute.

First step add position relative on container:

```
.label-container{
  position:relative;
}
```

Then add position: absolute on labels:

```
.label-slider{
  position: absolute;
}
```

And finaly just Adjust correctly with absolute as follow:

```
.label-slider:nth-child(1) {
  left:0;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(2) {
  left:25%;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(3) {
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: .5%;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(4) {
  right: 25%;
  transform: translateX(25%);
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(5) {
  right:0;
}
```

DEMO FULL

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran" rel="stylesheet);
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script");

body {
  font-family: "Catamaran", sans-serif;
  background: #2b8aeb;
}

.container {
  font-family: "Catamaran", sans-serif;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 50px 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow 0 6px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  color: #3949ab;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.label-container {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 100%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position : relative;
}

.label-slider {
  color: #3949ab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(1) {
  left:0;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(2) {
  left:25%;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(3) {
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin-left: .5%;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(4) {
  right: 25%;
  transform: translateX(25%);
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.label-slider:nth-child(5) {
  right:0;
}

.slider-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #dde5ff;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

input[type="range"],
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #dde5ff;
  outline: none;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #2b8aeb;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #1492ea;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 10;
}

input[type="range"]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.ticks {
   font-family: "Catamaran", sans-serif;
  color: #3949ab;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 6px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 15px;
    counter-reset: count -1;
}
.ticks > div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: silver;
  counter-increment: count 1;
}
.ticks > div:nth-child(5n - 4) {
  height: 200%;
}
.ticks > div:nth-child(5n - 4)::before {
  display: block;
  content: counter(count,decimal);
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="title">Range Sliders</p>

    <h4>Range Slider without steps</h4>
    <div class="slider-container">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="4" class="slider">
    </div>

    <div class="label-container">
      <div class="label-slider">None</div>
      <div class="label-slider">1</div>
      <div class="label-slider">2</div>
      <div class="label-slider">3</div>
      <div class="label-slider">4+</div>
    </div>

     

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry that i have not added  <div="container"><div> in my code...please heml me out in that case

Comment: No added it, I just said that you should removing the padding right and left into your container under a certain screen width with media querie

Comment: @shivachowdary just remove the padding, left, as I made in both demo

Comment: But numbers not not aligning with steps . This is where problem comes to me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..its working as expected